# How can a I publish data to a WCF duplex service, from non-Silverlight client

Tags: wcf

I have a Silverlight app, that uses a WCF duplex service extensively (therefore I don't want to change from duplex on that side of things).

I wish to stream data from a Windows app, via the WCF duplex service to any connected Silverlight client.  However I believe that only Silverlight clients have an API to call duplex WCF services (based on PollingDuplexBindingElement).

Therefore, I thought perhaps that I could have a non-duplex WCF service on the same website,to which the Windows client pushes data, and somehow trigger the duplex service to forward on the messages.  But to start with, the non-duplex service is effectively a windows app as well and gets the same errors if it tries to call the duplex service.

Finally, I have concluded I will have to use a shared queue / bus between the services and would like recommendations as to a good approach.  I am looking for the best performing (low latency) solution.

Answer (score 0):

The link below there is a good sample which consumes a wcf duplex service from a wpf client. 
http://petermcg.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/silverlight-polling-duplex-part-4-wpf-client/